# Differential equation with exactly two solutions .

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Every ODE(Ordinary Differential Equation) with initial condition has either unique solution or no solution or infinite many solutions. I want an example of an ODE( clearly without initial conditions) with exactly two solutions. Please provide me a simple example . I am unable to find that . Thank you.

Comment: Your first statement about every ODE with initial conditions having either 0,1,$\infty$ solns cannot be correct. e.g. Consider $y'(y'-1)=0,y(1)=1$.Perhaps you were referring to linear ODEs?

Comment: @Golden_Ratio ok then ODE given by you has more than one but finitely many solutions?

Comment: You can verify its solutions are $y(x)=1,y(x)=x$.

Comment: @Golden_Ratio https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/657284/if-an-ivp-does-not-enjoy-uniqueness-then-it-possesses-infinitely-many-solutions

Comment: @Golden_Ratio what about This question link ?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1568783/when-does-an-initial-value-problem-have-exactly-two-solutions

Comment: many thanks for sharing. But in that first link, in the solution alluding to Hellmuth Kneser, can I ask how does that proof ensure the newly constructed solution is differentiable at $t_0$? Applying that proof to my example would result in sharp points, for instance, if I have understood their construction correctly.

Comment: @Golden_Ratio may it’s about ODE of type $y’=(x,y),y(a)=b$ only .

Comment: yea I just realized that myself. So can we agree my example suffices as a counterexample to your first statement?

Comment: @Golden_Ratio these two solution $x$ and $1$ are clear but how can we say that there no other solutions?

Comment: well heuristically, if there are other solutions, they have to be piecewise either of the form $y=$constant or $y=x$+constant, correct? The issue is non-differentiability at sharp points where the pieces meet.

Comment: @Golden_Ratio seems to be correct. I will analysis it and comment you ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132929/discussion-between-golden-ratio-and-neelkanth).